# Improve performance in a big MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, innodb

I'd like to ask a question about how to improve performance in a big MySQL table using innodb engine:

There's currently a table in my database with around 200 million rows. This table periodically stores the data collected by different sensors. The structure of the table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE sns_value (
    value_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sensor_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    type_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    value int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (value_id),
    KEY idx_sensor id (sensor_id),
    KEY idx_date (date),
    KEY idx_type_id (type_id) );
```

At first, I thought of partitioning the table in months, but due to the steady addition of new sensors it would reach the current size in about a month.

Another solution that I came up with was partitioning the table by sensors. However, due to the limit of 1024 partitions of MySQL that wasn't an option.

I believe that the right solution would be using a table with the same structure for each of the sensors:

`sns_value_XXXXX`

This way there would be more than 1.000 tables with an estimated size of 30 million rows per year. These tables could, at the same time, be partitioned in months for fastest access to data.

What problems would result from this solution? Is there a more normalized solution?

**Editing with additional information**

I consider the table to be big in relation to my server:

- Cloud 2xCPU and 8GB Memory
- LAMP (CentOS 6.5 and MySQL 5.1.73)

Each sensor may have more than one variable types (CO, CO2, etc.).

I mainly have two slow queries:

1) Daily summary for each sensor and type (avg, max, min):

```
SELECT round(avg(value)) as mean, min(value) as min, max(value) as max, type_id
FROM sns_value
WHERE sensor_id=1 AND date BETWEEN '2014-10-29 00:00:00' AND '2014-10-29 12:00:00'
GROUP BY type_id limit 2000;
```

This takes more than 5 min.

2) Vertical to Horizontal view and export:

```
SELECT sns_value.date AS date,
sum((sns_value.value * (1 - abs(sign((sns_value.type_id - 101)))))) AS one,
sum((sns_value.value * (1 - abs(sign((sns_value.type_id - 141)))))) AS two,
sum((sns_value.value * (1 - abs(sign((sns_value.type_id - 151)))))) AS three
FROM sns_value
WHERE sns_value.sensor_id=1 AND sns_value.date BETWEEN '2014-10-28 12:28:29' AND '2014-10-29     12:28:29'
GROUP BY sns_value.sensor_id,sns_value.date LIMIT 4500;
```

This also takes more than 5 min.

**Other considerations**

1. Timestamps may be repeated due to inserts characteristics.
2. Periodic inserts must coexist with selects.
3. No updates nor deletes are performed on the table.

**Suppositions made to the "one table for each sensor" approach**

1. Tables for each sensor would be much smaller so access would be faster.
2. Selects will be performed only on one table for each sensor.
3. Selects mixing data from different sensors are not time-critical.

**Update 02/02/2015**

We have created a new table for each year of data, which we have also partitioned in a daily basis. Each table has around 250 million rows with 365 partitions. The new index used is as Ollie suggested (sensor_id, date, type_id, value) but the query still takes between 30 seconds and 2 minutes. We do not use the first query (daily summary), just the second (vertical to horizontal view).

In order to be able to partition the table, the primary index had to be removed.

Are we missing something? Is there a way to improve the performance?

Many thanks!

Comment: What problem is occurring with the current structure?

Comment: Big? WHat is big here?

Comment: What's the purpose of teis data? How should you read it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for the clear question. Please consider editing your question to describe how you intend to use these sensor readings. What will be your most heavily-used queries?

Comment: How open would you be to swapping to TokuDB engine opposed to using InnoDB?

Comment: I am open to any engine, even no-SQL if I can get better performance.

Comment: It's time to start a new question. That question should present your table definition, your query, and the explain plan from the query. If you have one table per year, it's not clear to me why you need to partition it by day. It's extraordinarily unlikely that partitioning will help performance in th the kind of summary query you are running: MySQL indexing works quite well and is simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ollie! We just changed the order of the columns in the index and voilà! The query takes now 1 second no matter the amount of data we retrieve. We have also removed the partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited based on changes to the question**

One table per sensor is, with respect, a very bad idea indeed. There are several reasons for that:

1. MySQL servers on ordinary operating systems have a hard time with thousands of tables. Most OSs can't handle that many simultaneous file accesses at once.
2. You'll have to create tables each time you add (or delete) sensors.
3. Queries that involve data from multiple sensors will be slow and convoluted.

My previous version of this answer suggested range partitioning by timestamp. But that won't work with your `value_id` primary key.  However, with the queries you've shown and proper indexing of your table, partitioning probably won't be necessary.

(Avoid the column name `date` if you can: it's a reserved word and you'll have lots of trouble writing queries. Instead I suggest you use `ts`, meaning timestamp.)

**Beware**: `int(11)` values aren't aren't big enough for your `value_id` column. You're going to run out of ids. Use `bigint(20)` for that column.

You've mentioned two queries. Both these queries can be made quite efficient with appropriate compound indexes, even if you keep all your values in a single table. Here's the first one.

```
SELECT round(avg(value)) as mean, min(value) as min, max(value) as max,
       type_id
  FROM sns_value
 WHERE sensor_id=1
  AND date BETWEEN '2014-10-29 00:00:00' AND '2014-10-29 12:00:00'
GROUP BY type_id limit 2000;
```

For this query, you're first looking up `sensor_id` using a constant, then you're looking up a range of `date` values, then you're aggregating by `type_id`. Finally you're extracting the `value` column.  Therefore, a so-called [compound covering index](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727) on `(sensor_id, date, type_id, value)` will be able to satisfy your query directly with an index scan. This should be very fast for you--certainly faster than 5 minutes even with a large table.

In your second query, a similar indexing strategy will work.

```
SELECT sns_value.date AS date,
       sum((sns_value.value * (1 - abs(sign((sns_value.type_id - 101)))))) AS one,
       sum((sns_value.value * (1 - abs(sign((sns_value.type_id - 141)))))) AS two,
       sum((sns_value.value * (1 - abs(sign((sns_value.type_id - 151)))))) AS three
  FROM sns_value
 WHERE sns_value.sensor_id=1
   AND sns_value.date BETWEEN '2014-10-28 12:28:29' AND '2014-10-29 12:28:29'
 GROUP BY sns_value.sensor_id,sns_value.date
 LIMIT 4500;
```

Again, you start with a constant value of `sensor_id` and then use a `date` range. You then extract both `type_id` and `value`. That means the same four column index I mentioned should work for you.

```
CREATE TABLE sns_value (
    value_id  bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sensor_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    type_id   int(11) NOT NULL,
    ts        timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    value int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY        (value_id),
  INDEX    query_opt (sensor_id, ts, type_id, value)
);
```

Comment: @DRapp The reason for indexes with rows swapped relates to how MySQL uses compound indexes to satisfy queries. When I suggested those two indexes, the original questioner had not yet disclosed the queries being used.

Comment: Why to add tehe value into the index?

Comment: If the entire query (including the value) can be satisfied from the index, without having to bounce back to the table, then the query can be much faster. Read this. http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Ollie. I will take a look at all the covering indexes thing and post the results.

Comment: We just added updated information on the results we got with the new index. Would it matter the order of the keys in the index?

Comment: Yes, the order of columns matters in covering indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Creating separate table for a range of sensors would be an idea.

Do not use the auto_increment for a primary key, if you dont have to. Usually DB engine is [clustering the data](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) by its primary key.

Use composite key instead, depends from your usecase, the sequence of columns may be different.

EDIT: Also added the type into the PK. Considering the queries, i would do it like this. Choosing the field names is intentional, they should be descriptive and always consider the reserverd words.

```
CREATE TABLE snsXX_readings (
    sensor_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    reading int(11) NOT NULL,
    reading_time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    type_id int(11) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (reading_time, sensor_id, type_id),
    KEY idx date_idx (date),
    KEY idx type_id (type_id) 
);
```

Also, consider summarizing the readings or grouping them into a single field.

Comment: You are correct about avoiding table separation and completely incorrect about your primary key suggestion. If anything, with MySQL and InnoDB the PK should always be auto_increment and nearly never compound or composite. The reason for that is that very clustering you mentioned and the way InnoDB uses PK for clustering.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me about primary key, can you refer to some materials about InnoDB and PK usage?

Comment: Percona have many interesting articles. I can't exactly give you a few links that contain all of it, but [this pdf](http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/percona-live/london-2011/PLUK2011-b-tree-indexes-and-innodb.pdf) should shed some lights on the matter. Personally, I've been reading articles and dabbling with InnoDB source code to get a grasp on what it does. To put it into simple terms, the next PK value should be always larger to avoid b-tree rebalance. Basically, auto_increment does that so it's almost always ideal candidate.

Comment: Having timestamp field in PK is incremental also and if you need to add the filter by this field, it helps in most cases. TokuDB seems to be a good hint also, will check it too. Thanks for the guidance! :)

Comment: The problem is that the timestamp *might* be incremental, there is no guarantee it will be :) however, if it indeed is always incremental (and unique) then there aren't any problems. However, there is also no guarantee that a sensor won't send two readings at the same second. Second is actually too high of a value here. My opinion on the matter is that auto_increment should be used here as a PK, just to get the potential cases with problems out of the way. The data won't be inflated that much, if at all (that has to be measured).

Answer (score 0):

You can try get randomize summary data

I have similar table. table engine myisam(smallest table size), 10m record, no index on my table because useless(tested).  Get all range for the all data. result:10sn this query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT sensor_id, value, date 
        FROM sns_value l 
        WHERE l.sensor_id= 123 AND 
        (l.date BETWEEN '2013-10-29 12:28:29' AND '2015-10-29 12:28:29') 
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2000 
    ) as tmp
    ORDER BY tmp.date;
```

This query on first step get between dates and sorting randomize first 2k data, on the second step sort data. the query every time get 2k result for different data.